# nsunknownkeyexception during segue

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

So im trying to write something with a UITableView that segues into a UITextview.

and in the UITextview there is a button to clear the text.
i have 2 questions.

right now im getting a error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:      '[<textViewController 0x6e69760> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key clearButton.'
```

the breakpoint says this is thrown when performSegue is called inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

here

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if( [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"fileSelected"]){
    textViewController *nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController ;
    nextViewController.title = @"newView";

    [nextViewController setText:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[self readFromFile:@"textfile.txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
}
```

and also. im trying to set the textview text with data i read from a file in the file systems
heres the read and write functions, which is not working...

```
-(NSData*) readFromFile:(NSString *)filename{
NSString* content = @"";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, filename];

content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

return [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
-(void) saveToFile:(NSString *)filename withData:(NSData *)data{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,filename];
[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

did i do something wrong during the segue, to cause the exception? if you need any other pieces of code, ill put it up .

thanks in advance

Comment: I think i figured out what's wrong.... the button that clears the text. its embedded into the UINavigationController's menu bar. so i think linking the button to the textview's controller is what broke the code.
is there a way to embbed a button into the UINavigationController's bar?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have a segue actually named "segueIdentifier". That would be a first step.

Comment: Yea i checked, in the template code, there is 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
does that need to be coded? or its fine without it

Comment: Suggest you solve one problem at a time  - 1. get the segue working, then 2. deal with your text stuff. So comment out the stuff in prepareForSegue and see if it still crashes. So what is  the "fileSelected" segue - that's a different segue, yes? Don't know what you are referring to by "template code"  - what is that?

Comment: The segue part is fixed. i don't removed the button and added it back.. some kind of magic but it doesn't crash anymore probably a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This problem appeared for me **after** the segue and was caused by a broken connection between view and controller:

[image: screenshot]
(the lower one is broken)

---

You just have to remove the connection and add it again.